# Morita equivalence for monoidal categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, morita-equivalence

I came across [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85768/morita-equivalence-for-categories) and it got me thinking. In monoidal categories we can define module and bi-module categories, so what can we say about morita equivalence in this situation? Which of the Morita theorems still hold, and do the equivalent statements still hold for categories without a ring-like structure such as semigroups or pomonoids?

Comment: What are pomonoids?

Comment: @DavidWhite Monoids with a left/right compatible partial order

Comment: @DavidWhite, a pomonoid is a monoid with a stable partial order.   Morita theory for monoids was studied by Knauer and Banachevski and behaves very well. It is of course a special case of the results for categories.  For semigroups Telwar developed a theory and he and others eventually got a  satisfactory theory for semigroups with $S=SS$.  This is also where people can do things for nonunital rings.  Valdis Laan and others have developed the theory for pomonoids but I am not an expert.